# Работа с Kivy, sqlite3

Tags: python, kivy

(Python,kivy)у меня есть 2 окна: регистрация и вход. Блок кода,который отвечает за регистрацию работает, далее есть окно со входом, пользователь указывает свои данные при регистрации и нажимает кнопку "войти", если пользователь ввел верные данные, его перекидывает на следующее окно, иначе вылезает текст с ошибкой. Проблема в том, что после нажатии кнопки "войти" ,следующее окно не открывается и ошибки никакой в консоли нет.

```
    RoundedButton:
        text:'Войти'
        size_hint:(None,None)
        height:40
        width:180
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5}
        on_press:root.user()

    class VhodWindow(Screen):
        def user(self):
            root2 = sqlite3.connect('reg2.db')
            cur = root2.cursor()
            root2.commit()
            cur.execute(f'SELECT Login FROM info2 WHERE Login = "{self.ids.log_vhod.text}"')
            r = cur.fetchone()               
            if  r is None:                        
                self.ids.error_label.text = 'Ошибка ввода'                       
            else: 
                self.ids.error_label.text = ''
                sleep(2)
                self.current = 'name_3'
                self.manager.transition.direction ='up'            
           root2.commit()
           root2.close()
```

Comment: on_press:root.user() а что тут должно произойти ?

Comment: это кнопка , к которой привязано событие , в данном случии функция user

Comment: а какой класс у этой функции юзера ? где там root ?